# Rolling up addition using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to add third column or modify second column by addition of previous row value score. I'm getting date-wise two table addition but can't get serial addition of data.

DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE 1_bugs 
( id int(11) NOT NULL
, date date NOT NULL
, cf1 int(11) NOT NULL
, cf2 int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

INSERT INTO 1_bugs (id, date, cf1, cf2) VALUES 
(1, '2016-07-19', 3, 2), 
(2, '2016-07-19', 2, 1), 
(3, '2016-07-22', 2, 2);
```

Query:

```
SELECT table.date1, IFNULL(table.cf1 + bugs.cf2),0) as score
FROM table GROUP BY table.date1;
```

Output:

```
| date1 | score  |
| 2016-07-19 | 5 |
| 2016-07-19 | 3 |
| 2016-07-22 | 4 |
```

Expected:

```
| date1 | score  | Total score  |
| 2016-07-19 | 5 | 5 |
| 2016-07-19 | 3 | 8 |
| 2016-07-22 | 4 | 12 |
```

I have tried rollup but it doesn't give output as expected and just adds null row with addition of all score values.

```
| date1 | score  |
| 2016-07-19 | 5 |
| 2016-07-19 | 3 |
| 2016-07-22 | 4 |
| null       | 12 |
```

How can I get output like expected?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Can you re-read too? Not mentioned create, insert and expected, actual, problem already? Better can you answer it please if you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , x.cf1+x.cf2 sub_total
     , SUM(y.cf1+y.cf2) running
  FROM 1_bugs x 
  JOIN 1_bugs y 
    ON y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----------+---------+
| id | date       | cf1 | cf2 | sub_total | running |
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | 2016-07-19 |   3 |   2 |         5 |       5 |
|  2 | 2016-07-19 |   2 |   1 |         3 |       8 |
|  3 | 2016-07-22 |   2 |   2 |         4 |      12 |
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for fast and perfect answer! I have one question, i have couple of tables and when i'm joining it is giving me issue. Do you want me to add note over here or you want me to create new question so you can answer over there?

Comment: Ask a fresh question, referencing this one