# Get rolled up sub total and total by joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Extending [Rolling up addition using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527516/rolling-up-addition-using-mysql/38531931?noredirect=1#comment64459120_38531931)

I can get rolling sum of rows https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry's answer for basic stuff so i tried to extend query by joining multiple tables but 1_keyworddefs.name='K2' is not affected. Getting same answer for 1_keyworddefs.name='K1' and K2.

## Working query but directly by specifying 1_bugs.bug_id='2':

```
SELECT x.*, x.cf1 + x.cf2 sub_total, sum(y.cf1 + y.cf2) total FROM 1_bugs x INNER JOIN 1_bugs y ON y.bug_id <= x.bug_id INNER JOIN 1_keywords ON 1_keywords.bug_id = y.bug_id WHERE (x.bug_date BETWEEN '2016-07-19' AND '2016-07-22') AND (x.bug_id='2') AND (y.bug_status = 'VERIFIED' OR y.bug_status = 'CLOSED') AND (1_keywords.bug_id = x.bug_id) GROUP BY x.bug_id
```

## Exact output (but i want to join table where 1_keywords.bug_id=1_bugs.bug_id matches instead of directly specifying 1_bugs.bug_id='2'):

```
bug_id  bug_date    cf1     cf2     bug_status  sub_total   total   
2       2016-07-19  2       1       VERIFIED    3           3
```

## Non-working query by joining tables (expecting answer like above):

```
SELECT x.*, x.cf1 + x.cf2 sub_total, sum(y.cf1 + y.cf2) total FROM 1_bugs x INNER JOIN 1_bugs y ON y.bug_id <= x.bug_id LEFT JOIN 1_keywords ON 1_keywords.bug_id = y.bug_id LEFT JOIN 1_keyworddefs ON 1_keyworddefs.id=1_keywords.keywordid AND 1_keyworddefs.name='K2' and 1_keywords.bug_id = y.bug_id WHERE (x.bug_date BETWEEN '2016-07-19' AND '2016-07-22') AND (y.bug_status = 'CLOSED' OR y.bug_status = 'VERIFIED') GROUP BY x.bug_id;
```

## Expected:

```
bug_id  bug_date    cf1     cf2     bug_status  sub_total   total   
2       2016-07-19  2       1       VERIFIED    3           3
```

## Actual:

```
 bug_id     bug_date    cf1     cf2     bug_status  sub_total   total   
 2          2016-07-19  2       1       VERIFIED    3           3
 3          2016-07-22  2       2       CLOSED      4           7
```

** Here bug_id -> 3 row comes wrongly because 1_bugs.bug.id=1_keywords.bug_id doesn't match and there is no 1_keywords.bug_id='3' present in 1_keywords table.

DDLs:

```
-- 1_bugs table1 (master table) :

CREATE TABLE `1_bugs` (`bug_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `bug_date` date NOT NULL, `cf1` int(11) NOT NULL, `cf2` int(11) NOT NULL, `bug_status` varchar(200) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `1_bugs` (`bug_id`, `bug_date`, `cf1`, `cf2`, `bug_status`) VALUES (1, '2016-07-19', 3, 2, 'RESOLVED'), (2, '2016-07-19', 2, 1, VERIFIED'), (3, '2016-07-22', 2, 2, 'CLOSED');

-- 1_keywords table2 (having keyword ids):

CREATE TABLE `1_keywords` (`bug_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `keywordid` varchar(11) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `1_keywords` (`bug_id`, `keywordid`) VALUES (1, 'K1'), (2, 'K2');


-- 1_keyworddefs table3 (having keyword names according to keywordid):

CREATE TABLE `1_keyworddefs` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `1_keyworddefs` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES (1, 'K1', 'My K1 item'), (2, 'K2', 'My K2 item');
```

Can someone please point me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I made a progress in this and almost near except keyword name is not getting affected, can someone take  a look now? Editing query and answer of it.

Comment: Remember the steps you went through last time?

Comment: I'm sorry man! I have entered almost all information needed instead of like my first post, can you point me exact issue so i can improve it and add missing info?

Comment: You haven't provided a desired result.

Comment: See now, thanks Strwaberry for helping me out. One more time your help needed to get output by joining tables as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: '... JOIN 1_bugs y ON y.bug_id <= x.bug_id ...' did you mean 'y.bug_id = x.bug_id' ?

Comment: I think no because we won't get rolling sum of it. Strawberry is the best person to answer you why :)

Comment: No. I don't see. I merely repeated comments I made previously. Anyway, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b39248/4

Comment: Hi Strwaberry, you are rockstar! Almost near to answer except one of the major issue about count, when we search using particular keyword which was main objective -> it gives wrong count of total. Here is the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/132ec7/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously things where not clear... after long discussions turns out what you wanted was to extract from bugzilla database a list of bugs for specific keyword grouped by date and a sum of cf1 + cf2 and the same sum of only 'opened' and 'verified' bugs.

Here we go

```
SELECT
  b.lastdiffed,
  d.name,
  d.description,
  SUM(IF(b.bug_status IN('CLOSED', 'VERIFIED'), b.cf1 + b.cf2, 0)) AS sub_total,
  SUM(b.cf1 + b.cf2) AS running
FROM
  bugs AS b
  JOIN keywords AS k
    ON ( k.bug_id = b.bug_id )
  JOIN keyworddefs AS d
    ON ( d.id = k.keywordid )
WHERE 
  1
  AND d.name = 'SONY'
GROUP BY (b.lastdiffed)
ORDER BY b.lastdiffed ASC
```

Giving this result

```
+------------+------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| lastdiffed | name | description | sub_total | running |
+------------+------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 2016-05-20 | SONY | sony items  |         7 |       7 |
| 2016-06-20 | SONY | sony items  |        11 |      17 |
| 2016-06-27 | SONY | sony items  |         5 |       5 |
| 2016-06-29 | SONY | sony items  |         5 |       5 |
+------------+------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but total is wrong, it is same as sub_total.

Comment: Sorry Antony but i need a total = previous row total + current total as well which i'm getting using Strawberry's answer but giving me issue when trying to match bug+keyword with 1_keywords.bug_id=1_bugs.bug_id AND 1_keyworddefs.name=1_keywords.keywordid.

Comment: I got a same output like question's actual output if i specify y.bug_id <= x.bug_id in your query so looks like you are very near too. Thanks for your effort but can you give a try for me to match keyword name as well ? Please if you want to re-create, much appreciated your help sir!